# Is it possible to use Mongo's Ops Manager with a DocumentDB instance on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, aws

We currently use Ops Manager to manage our on-prem MongoDB instances.  We are, however, moving toward using native AWS services instead.  As such, we are looking to use DocumentDB with our newer projects instead of our MongoDB instance.

Can somebody tell me whether or not Mongo's Ops Manager can work on DocumentDB instances?  I've tried any number of Google searches and don't get any real answer either way.

Full disclosure: I'm not a DBA, I'm just the guy who is trying to manage/plan portions of our Cloud Migration strategy.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It's the idea of cloud bases services that you don't have to operate the database, that's why you pay Amazon for it. In my opinion, AWS DocumentDB is quite limited compared to native MongoDB, see all the "No" entries in [Supported MongoDB APIs, Operations, and Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html).

Answer (score 0):

AWS DocumentDB is the MongoDB compatible NoSQL document database solution.
It is a managed service which means you don't have to deal with hardware, software and patches. Additionally the DocumentDB service automatically takes backup of your database based on the configuration you provide and enables point in time restore. So you don't have to deal with many server and database administrator tasks on this managed service platform.

As application developer, you should handle index operations.
Although CloudWatch provides a monitoring solution by integrating Ops Manager with CloudWatch data, you can monitor your application from Ops Manager and identify performance issues within your familiar tool.

I'ld suggest go with native solutions as much as possible and where your governance and operations require build integrations to your current management solutions from AWS platform